# SQL Server Varbinary(Max) - The space occupied

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a question about the `Varbinary(MAX)` datatype in SQL Server.

I want to implement something in an application which the people download and upload files to the database and it's already made, in .net WebForms, but there is a problem. The database of my company has a problem with space and they are afraid that these inserts of files will affect a lot the space in the database.

The files are mainly PDF's, but my question is, when I upload a file, let's imagine, with 2MB, will the `VarBinary(MAX)` occupy 2MB or will it be shorter?

Comment: Why would it be shorter? Have you tried testing this out and looking at the size of your table before and after an insert?

Comment: Space considerations should usually come quite far down the list. The first question I'd want to answer is, do these documents have to be *transactionally consistent* with other data stored in the database? If the answer is yes then you really do need the documents to be "in" the database and so storage space *is* going to be consumed in that server's storage. (Then the specifics such as `FILESTREAM` need to be considered)

Comment: There's a whole section of the SQL Server documentation dedicated to [Data compression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/data-compression/data-compression)

Comment: If you have data compression turned on, you may see smaller files, but maybe not, depending on the original file (just like zipping a file does not always decrease the size). Another option you can consider is to store the files somewhere else, and store links to the file's location in the database itself. Downsides include that this will open you up to having files get lost or out of sync, and you will have to arrange backup separately for them, but it is an option to consider.